# Optimize time to complete request to external service (Solr) hosted locally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, solr, .net-core, localhost

I am working on Dot Net Core MVC project where I am making several request to Solr query api. The application and Solr Core, both are on the same Windows Server. Each request to Solr takes about 20 to 25 ms to complete. How can we reduce that and make it faster. The query time in Solr is mostly at 1 to 2 ms.

Solr is hosted locally and we are expecting a better response.

How can we reduce this time which is taking 20 to 25 ms per request. What are the best practices to optimize the time it took to complete request to solr hosted locally?

Comment: First - use a profiler to find out what's actually taking time. If Solr is returning a result in a couple of milliseconds, you're probably seeing the overhead of serialization and deserialization on each side.

Comment: How can I find how much time it takes for serialization / deserialization  ?

Comment: Use a profiler (it's built in to Visual Studio). It should be able to tell you exactly what parts of your code is spending time where.

Comment: @MatsLindh I just noticed that its not serialization related, because a request to Solr which doesn't return any records is taking same time. What it could be? May be its because of latency or something else?

Comment: Which would be what a profiler should be able to tell you :-)

Comment: Would you share your query? Maybe you are using functions, maybe you do some sorting. There are some variables we don't know.

Comment: I don't think it matters, as the query itself is returning results in 1 ms into Solr